# Print only parent categories of post in custom RSS feed

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I'm trying to print only the parent category for each post and a permalink to that category within a custom Wordpress RSS feed.

Using `<?php the_category_rss(); ?>` prints all categories for a post (parent and child categories) like this:

```
<category><![CDATA[Category 1]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[Category 2]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[Category 3]]></category>
```

I'd like to print only the parent categories for a post rather than parent and child categories.

I'm also looking for the proper way to print the parent category's permalink within the RSS feed.

I have a feeling the way to do this is a filter, but I'm not sure how to implement it. This is what I have right now, but it returns a `1` instead of the parent category name:

```
add_filter('the_category_rss', 'only_parent_rss_categories');

function only_parent_rss_categories( $allparents ) {

    $categories = get_the_category();
    $category = $category->category_parent == 0;

    $allparents= esc_html("<category><![CDATA[{$category}]]></category>");

    return $allparents;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still interested in hearing how this can be accomplished using the Wordpress function `the_category_rss()`, but I did find another way to do this:

```
<?php $parentsonly = ""; 
  // loop through categories
  foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    // exclude child categories
    if ($category->category_parent == 0) {
      $parentsonly = '<category domain="' . get_category_link($category->cat_ID) . '">' . $category->name . '</category>'; 
    } 
  }
echo $parentsonly; ?>
```

This returns each parent category in the proper RSS validated format, using `<category>` and `domain` for the category URL:

`<category domain="http://www.yourdomain.com/category-archive/">`My Category`</category>`

Hope this helps someone else!